# Text Image Text inline HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to have text and then an image with text following? I dont want to use table if possible but I am running into issues with the items breaking onto their own lines.

Below is my code and css so far:

```
<div id="header_number">
    <h2 class="phone_title">Call Us Today!</h2>
    <img src="images/phone_icon.jpg" alt="Call us Today"/>
    <h2 class="large_num">1-800-555-9999</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h2.phone_title{font: 13px arial;Color:#013173;text-align:left;}
h2.large_num{font:29px arial;Color:#013173;text-align:left;}
#header_number{float:right;height:60px;width:332px;display:inline;}
```

I thought the `display:inline;` in the container div (header_number) would line everything up but that didn't work. If needed I can add a class to the `img` and float everything left if that is my only option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now **Define** your **some element** `display:inline-block;` **or** `vertical-align:top`

**as like this**

```
h2.phone_title, h2.large_num, img
{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;
margin:0;
}
```

Now check to ***[live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/qOqxX8i1)***

Comment: Great that is exactly what I was looking to do. Thanks for the help I learned the correct way to use the display attribute.